# How-to create a batch file for network drive mapping

Tags: batch-file, networking, windows-10, drive

I will create a batch file for network drive mapping to use for different users which will create a mapped network drive location to a text.file
For example, I have different users and everyone has different network drive mappingand I do not want to instal everything manually for every person

thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have so far? for network map, you can use subst command. Where is the issue?

Comment: For example \\PATH-NETWORK-SHARE\FOLDER-NAME

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ As suggested by @EylM; please provide the code that you have tried so far. This will help other SO contributors to read your post and help with your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of 2 commands (This will map the folder to a local k: drive):

```
net use k: \\PATH-NETWORK-SHARE\FOLDER-NAME
```

OR

```
 subst k: \\PATH-NETWORK-SHARE\FOLDER-NAME
```

Comment: how can save path network in a text file? can you please write completely